# How to output nested object keys separated by a dot - JS

Tags: javascript

Code:

```js
const obj = {
  client: {
    id: 1,
    personal: {
      name: "Mike"
    }
  },
  address: {
    street: "streetname"
  }
};

function recursiveKeys(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
      Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach((innerKey) => {
        console.log(`${key}.${innerKey}`);
      });
    }
  });
}

recursiveKeys(obj);
```

Desired output:

```
client.id
client.personal.name
address.street
```

This code works only for a 2 level object, but it won't work for a 3rd-4th level and deeper, is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: lodash can be your best friend :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `recursiveKeys` actually recursive. Pass along the partial property string from the parent object on each recursive call.

```js
const obj = {
  client: {
    id: 1,
    personal: {
      name: "Mike"
    }
  },
  address: {
    street: "streetname"
  }
};

function recursiveKeys(obj, propStr = '') {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    const nestedPropStr = propStr + (propStr ? '.' : '') + key;
    if (typeof val === 'object') recursiveKeys(val, nestedPropStr);
    else console.log(nestedPropStr);
  });
}
recursiveKeys(obj);
```

Comment: What if I want to find nested key by value. e.g. I am looking for `name` "Mike" and I should get key `client.personal.name`? Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: recursion!

```js
const obj = {
  client: {
    id: 1,
    personal: {
      name: "Mike"
    }
  },
  address: {
    street: "streetname"
  }
};

function recursiveKeys(obj) {
  const keys = []
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key]) {
    //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--- the function calls itself
      recursiveKeys(obj[key]).forEach(innerKey => {
        keys.push(`${key}.${innerKey}`)
      })
    }else{
      keys.push(key)
    }
  });
  return keys
}

console.log(recursiveKeys(obj));
```

If you have access to the new `Array#flatMap()` method, you can use it to make this even more elegant:

```js
const obj = {
  client: {
    id: 1,
    personal: {
      name: "Mike"
    }
  },
  address: {
    street: "streetname"
  }
};

function recursiveKeys(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).flatMap(key => 
    typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key]
      ? recursiveKeys(obj[key]).map(innerKey => `${key}.${innerKey}`)
      : key
  );
}

console.log(recursiveKeys(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

> This code works only for a 2 level object, but it won't work for a
> 3rd-4th level and deeper, is there a clean way to achieve this?

The problem is you should make your `recursiveKeys` as it is with 3 steps:

1. Determine the key result named `keyRes`
2. Check if the inner content is an object, then recursive it.
3. Print the `keyRes` along with getting out of the recursive, important to avoid infinite loop !!!

```js
const obj = {
  client: {
    id: 1,
    personal: {
      name: "Mike"
    }
  },
  address: {
    street: "streetname"
  }
};

function recursiveKeys(obj, previousKey = '') {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    let keyRes = previousKey ? `${previousKey}.${key}` : key; // Step 1 
    if (typeof values === 'object')  // Step 2
      recursiveKeys(values, keyRes); 
    else // Step 3
      console.log(keyRes); 
  });

}

recursiveKeys(obj);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, why you chose `Object.entries()` instead of `Object.keys()`?

Comment: Because I have to use both `key` and `value` of each `object`. 
`key` to determine `keyRes` in `Step 1`, `value` to use for `Step 2` to make it as **recursive**.

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for more details about `Object.entries()`.

Comment: ah, i see, thanks.

Comment: The [answer of @CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950507/9071943) is good. So you should mark his answer as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future :D